Upgrade postgres driver pq to pgx in golang
I want to upgrade postgres library pq to pgx in golang. As there is no support of pq now.
pq: https://github.com/lib/pq
pgx: https://github.com/jackc/pgx
I am using these call of pq in my code

pq.Listener
pq.NewListener
pq.EventCallbackType
pq.ListenerEventReconnected
pq.ListenerEventDisconnected

But I am not able to find these equivalent methods of pq in pgx.
Any how I can upgrade this, is these are not available in new upgraded package?
Thanks.

if you are using pq.Listener, all you need to do is integrate your logic within the notification handling loop. there wouldn't be any issues after.
